# convert from JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<Integer,Integer>> to JavaPairRDD<String, Integer>

Tags: java, apache-spark, mapreduce

Helloy. I'm new to spark.
I have a result of the form:
(test,(1,1)) (spark,(1,2))

I need to get a minimum of two values and to convert it to look: 
(test,1) (spark,1)

How to do it correctly?
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEHIZ.png)

Comment: Not quite sure what the coding has to do with minimum. Minimum of n numbers is not word counting. Am I missing something> Also, try using Scala, using Java is too much work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it i use only mapToPair.
[all code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loEnK.png)